# How do I "Import" a TypeScript module using StackBlitz editor

Tags: angular, typescript

If I go into the [Stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com) editor and create a new Angular project, it provides some default files, folders, etc.

Under the "Dependencies" area, I want to install [`shortid`](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/shortid). So, I type that into the box and it goes through the motions of loading the correct version. All is well and good at that point.

Then, in the `app.component.ts` file, it is my understanding that this can be "imported" - but any combination of the following fails with the message "Cannot find module 'shortid'."

```
import * as sid from 'shortid';
import { generate } from 'shortid';
import "/node_modules/shortid";
import shortid = require("shortid");
```

The following doesn't generate an error, but also does not seem to expose any of the `shortid` functions.

```
import 'shortid';
```

Is StackBlitz broken in this regard? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some packages don't have a default export, so you need to:

```
import * as shortid from 'shortid';
```

Working StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kr9x7m

Edit: I mis-read your question. IntelliSense isn't working for me either, but shortid is working as expected.

Comment: So, it is a problem with StackBlitz... because when I do that, even though it complains, the functionality works as expected. Gah!

Comment: Yes, it appears so. Other users have reported similar issues: https://github.com/stackblitz/core/issues/87 with no resolution.

Comment: Stackblitz likes to complain now with a red squiggly line (under 'shortid' in your example) but it will still work. In my case, using Muuri, I had to call new Muuri.default instead of new Muuri to get it to work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Closing my application and reopening worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a note to anyone with this problem or similar problem and ends up on this question; even if Stackblitz complains that it does not recognize a module, it might still work when you run the code. The error message is likely simply a result of a security feature in the browser (in the browser console, you might see something like

```
Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The target origin provided does not match the recipient window's origin ('https://stackblitz.com').
```

You can most often ignore this and just run your code